# Is this a subspace? $X = \{x \in \mathbb R^2: x \cdot y = 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am completely lost in this question and hoping someone could explain this question through for me.

Let $y=[1,2]$

$X = \{x \in \mathbb R^2: x \cdot y = 0\}$

Is $X$ a subspace?

So I get the equation:
$x_1 + 2x_2 = 0 $. For it to be a subspace, it has to include the $0$ vector (which it does right?), has to be closed in addition, and be able to multiply by a constant. Where I get completely lost is understanding what values $x$ can take. For it to be closed under addition, $x + y$ must be in the subspace so am I only looking for x-values where $x_1 + 2x_2 = 0$ is satisfied? So if I take $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = 1$ which doesn't satisfy the equation, does this mean $X$ is not a subspace?

Sorry if there are formatting errors; first post! Thanks

Comment: Wellcome! I just edited your question so that it is a bit easier to read. But there are something in the middle that  I don't quite understand what you mean. Please again edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to know exactly what values $x$ has to take. First notice that X is subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore, we only have to check if it is closed under addition, closed under multiplication  and the zero is contained in order to determine if it is subspace. So to verify those conditions, you basically assume you take two elements/ one element of $X$ and see if the addition of them/multiplication with a scalar also satisfies the property, which qualifies them to be in $X$ ( this property for an $x$ is $x \cdot y = 0$ in order $x$ to be in $X$). You then check if that condition is satisfied also by $0$, to conclude that $0 \in X$.

1. Closure under addition:

Assume $x_1,x_2 \in X$, then $(x_1+x_2)\cdot y = x_1\cdot y + x_2 \cdot y = 0$, hence $x_1 + x_2 \in X$. done.

2. Closure under multiplication:

Assume $x_1 \in X$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lambda x_1 \cdot y = \lambda (x_1 \cdot y) = 0$, hence $\lambda x_1 \in X$. done.

3. zero is an element of $X$:
   since $0\cdot y = 0$, $0 \in X$. done.

Let me know in case any step is not clear.